# html test runner for sikuli, adding a screenshot in my report

Tags: html, sikuli, test-runner

I am using `Sikuli` and create my reports with `htmltestrunner`.  I want to "print" a screen-shot in my reports but seems that the `<pre>` tags used by `htmltestrunners` do not show the image but just the code.

The code I use in my script is:

```
someclass.screenshot("1.jpg")
   print("<img src=\"1.jpg\">")
```

Screen-shot is created in the same folder as my report but the report instead of image would render:

`pt1.1: test`
`<img src="1.jpg">`

in html:

`<pre>

pt1.1: test
&lt;img src="1.jpg" /&gt;
        </pre>`

How to force it to display my image?